# react-native-screens has been ignored because it contains invalid configuration. Reason: "dependency.platforms.android.componentDescriptors" not allow

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-reanimated-v2, react-native-screens

I'm facing this issue

> Package react-native-screens has been ignored because it contains invalid configuration. Reason: "dependency.platforms.android.componentDescriptors" is not allowed

Comment: https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-screens/issues/1614

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem when I updated the gradle-wrapper.properties from 6.7.1 to 7.5. To resolve temporarily the problem i reversed the change and the build was good. I will update when upgrade a gain. Maybe in this link you could find the solution.

https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-screens/issues/1614

Gretings!